# Wifi hardware not working and not found on Acer Aspire One D255

Tags: networking, wireless, acer, aspire

The wireless worked perfectly under Windows7. I have just installed UBUNTU and tried various commands like "nmcli" and "lshw -C network" and "nmcli device show" and more, but no sign of a wireless adapter on the list of results.

What do I try next?

Comment: What about `lspci`?

Comment: Yes, tried that. No mention of wireless there.

Comment: What's your Ubuntu version?

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply. I asked my daughter to have a friend look at it. No result.

The Ubuntu version is 18.04.1 LTS and I have just checked for updates over LAN. All up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:->

1. Is your Wired Ethernet detected by the new install?
2. if yes > Then go to system settings > software sources > additional drivers
3. scan for additional wifi driver install and restart system

Refer: [Detailed description for installing additional drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-additional-drivers)

Comment: I've installed Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS

I don't see "system settings > software sources > additional drivers". Is there a power user mode or something? It all looks very basic from here.

Comment: OK. I found it and did a search for additional drivers with the result: "No additional drivers available."

What's next??